# Sorted set with fast lookup (as fast as HashSet?)

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, hashmap, treemap

I'm looking for some kind of set data structure that can meet both of these requirements:

1. Sorted
2. O(1) for lookup

This is what I got so far, but I really hope there's an existing, less-awkward, data structure out there.

```
/**
 * This MUST support both 
 * (1) Looking up by A - O(n)
 * (2) Iteration by sorted Foo<A, B>
 */
public class MySet<Foo<A, B>> extends TreeSet<Foo<A, B>>
{ 
    private Map<A, Foo<A, B>> temp = new HashMap<A, Foo<A, B>>();

    public Foo<A, B> getNode(A a)
    {
       return temp.get(a);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Foo<A, B> foo)
    {
       temp.put(foo.getA(), foo);
       return super.add(foo);
    }
}
```

And my `Foo` class looks like this:

```
public class Foo<A, B>
{
    private A a; //Can NEVER be null
    private B b; //Can NEVER be null

    //... constructor and stuff omitted 

    public int compareTo(Foo<A, B> that)
    {
        if (this.equals(that))
           return 0;

        //Compare by a first
        int ret = this.a.compareTo(that);
        if (ret == 0)
            return 0;

        //Compare by b
        return this.b.compareTo(that.b);            
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj instanceof Foo))
            return false;

        Foo rhs = (Foo) obj;

        return this.a.equals(rhs.a) && this.b.equals(rhs.b);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's a use case for my set:

```
MySet<Foo<SomeA, SomeB>> mySet = getTheData(); //getTheData() returns a set with a bunch of Foo objects

SomeA a = getA(); //getA() returns some instance of SomeA that I'm interested in
```

I want to be able to check the set and RETRIEVE a Foo object (if exists) such that Foo.getA() == a;

```
mySet.getNode(a);
```

Comment: Why is O(log n) lookup not acceptable? That's already quite fast.

Comment: Actually, it is acceptable then, BUT, how am I going to retrieve a value from a TreeSet on the fly? I want to be able to look up by foo.getA(), not just check the tree the see if the element is in there.

Comment: You'd use a TreeMap. But you need both lookup by `A` and iteration sorted by `Foo<A, B>`? Then there is no good way around having two structures anyway. (You *could* probably mash a hash table and a sorted set together but it'll be a lot of nasty work and probably not even more efficient).

Comment: Looking up by `A` and iteration sorted by `Foo<A, B>` is exactly what I needs! And yeah, I figure it's gonna take a lot of mashing up multiple data structures together.

Comment: Well if you don't insert often, just keep a separate hash map and a binary search tree. If you do insert often, the tree set will be the bottleneck and you will have to live with Omega(log n) per op.

Comment: @abcXYZ what is the complexity of insertion you need ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by using some additional space. So you need a HashSet. Additionally, each element will point to the next value in the sort order. Let's say you have keys 1, 3, 5, 10 and you are using linear probing.

```
value array   =  [3, 5, null, null, 10,   1];
pointer array =  [1, 4, null, null, null, 0];
```

So the value array contains the values. The hash function decides where the value goes. so in the above example, h(1) = 5 (1 goes to index 5), h(3) = 0, h(5) = 1, and h(10) = 4. The indexes 2, 3 have null (open spaces for future elements). The pointer array says which element follows the current element in the sorting order. So let's say we are doing set.contains(3), it will result in computing h(3) (which will yield 0), and we know that the element exists in the set. If we want the next element in the set of elements according to sort order, we look at the value in the pointer array. So for value 3 (which is at position 0 in the value array), we get the next element in the sort order by looking up the index in the pointer array (pointer_array[0], which is 1), and then looking up value_array[1], which is 5.

This is a very common implementation. Java's LinkedHashMap is usually used as a LRU cache, which is implemented as a hash map + a doubly linked list of keys. The keys in the doubly linked list are in the order of their access.

In your case, when you insert an element, you need to adjust your pointer array which is very slow. You have to do a linear scan. **If this is not read only, you can use the following approach**.

In your data structure, have a hashset and a avl tree, a red black tree or any other balanced binary tree. Whenever you do a containsKey test, it's *O(1)*. Whenever you are enumerating, you can traverse them using the binary tree in sorted order in *linear time*. Whenever you are inserting a new element, you also insert it into both the binary tree and HashSet. When you delete, you delete the element from the hash set and the binary tree. So deletes and inserts become *O(log n)*.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should try using MultiMaps in google guava library.
Its pretty simple to use also:

```
Map<Salesperson, List<Sale>> map = new Hashmap<SalesPerson, List<Sale>>();
public void makeSale(Salesperson salesPerson, Sale sale) {
    List<Sale> sales = map.get(salesPerson);
    if (sales == null) {
      sales = new ArrayList<Sale>();
      map.put(salesPerson, sales);
    }
    sales.add(sale);
}
```

can be replaced by,

```
Multimap<Salesperson, Sale> multimap = new ArrayListMultimap<Salesperson,Sale>();
public void makeSale(Salesperson salesPerson, Sale sale) {
    multimap.put(salesperson, sale);
}
```

But you have to be careful here, multimaps will preserve the entries with same keys unlike hashmaps which replaces the equivalent keys with the latest one.

Google Guava Libraries feature a lot of other data structures with different functionality. You can find the information about it on its wiki.

Hope this was helpful.